# How to refresh a table created on top of a view

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake and I have created a table(123) on top of a view(123Dummy) with the following codes

```
create or replace table 123 as select * from 123Dummy;
```

The view has 10 records and by default, the table also has 10 records. The problem is, how do I get an updated version of the view in the table when an update has been done to the view? for example when the number of records in the view has increased to 15, if I run a select * on the table it will still have the number(10) of record from when the table was created.

is there a way to refresh the table?

Comment: can  you not create a view on top a view `create or replace view v123 as select * from Dummy123;` ? Also i dont think you can create anything starts with number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE … AS SELECT (CTAS)` is used to create a table and populate it immediately using provided SQL query. There is no connection between the created table and dependent object inside SELECT query afterwards.

```
CREATE TABLE tab_trg
AS
SELECT * FROM tab_src;
```

Expectation that when `tab_src` is updated will trigger automatic update of `tab_trg` is invalid.

Options:

1. Create a view instead of table:

   `CREATE VIEW tab_trg AS SELECT * FROM tab_src;`
2. Recreate the table periodically(outside scheduler or [TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task)):

   `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab_trg COPY GRANTS AS SELECT * FROM tab_src;`
3. [Dynamic Tables - Delivering Declarative Streaming Data Pipelines with Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/dynamic-tables-delivering-declarative-streaming-data-pipelines/):

> Dynamic Tables are a new table type in Snowflake that lets teams use simple SQL statements to declaratively define the result of your data pipelines. Dynamic Tables also automatically refresh as the data changes, only operating on new changes since the last refresh.
>
> ```
> CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] DYNAMIC TABLE 
> LAG = ' { seconds | minutes | hours | days }'
> WAREHOUSE = 
> AS SELECT
> ```

[Dynamic Tables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/dynamic-tables-about)

> A dynamic table is a table that materializes the results of a query that you specify. Rather than creating a separate target table and writing code to transform and update the data in that table, you can define the target table as a dynamic table, and you can specify the SQL statement that performs the transformation. An automated process updates the materialized results automatically through regular (and often incremental) refreshes

Comment: :) Why not creating a view instead of mat view. if its not billions of rows, view is preferable.